# Android Google Services Ad Failing to load

Tags: android, admob, google-play-services

My ad is failing to load inside my add and I'm unsure why this is. I would be grateful if anyone could solve my issue.

```
    adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
    adView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);
    FrameLayout layout = new FrameLayout(this);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
        .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
        .build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
    layout.addView(adView);
```

LogCat screenshot:
http://puu.sh/8sxZN.png

Manifest Parts:

```
       <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
           android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
```

AND

```
 <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
         android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
```

Entire On Create:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    a = getSharedPreferences("userdata",0);
    b = a.edit();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
    adView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);
    FrameLayout layout = new FrameLayout(this);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
        .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
        .addTestDevice("065294C80051124D2AB59139999F3202")
        .build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
    layout.addView(adView);
    auth = new Authenticate(b, a, d);
    if (auth.auth){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }else{
         newFragment = new login();

            newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "missiles");


    }
    localData= new LocalDataInterface(b,c);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
    }
}
```

Entire Layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
   </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can u post your manifest. Also where do u add the FrameLayout ?

Comment: Post your layout and the entirety of the #onCreate method.

Answer (score 0):

1 you should add a reference to google-play-services_lib project

2 at your application manifest you should add this (into application tag):

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

3 your device must have **gapps** installed

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @Zakari suggested, make sure that the following checkbox is unticked.

```
Settings->Data Usage->Google Service->Restrict Background Data
```